# Link malformed in automatically converted answer to trivial comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, convert-to-comment

I'm not sure if this is a problem at all as this is the first time I'm posting a link (as I don't have enough rep to post comments) but my answer which points to an answer was automatically converted to a trivial comment, but the link was malformed.

[Comment in question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31440203/3073551):

```
You might want to take a look at this: [Detailed answer][1] [1]: stackoverflow.com/a/27995734/3073551
```

I might be doing something wrong, if so could you please tell me what?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Actually, interestingly enough, the "trivial answer converted to comment" functionality is in a completely different section of code from the moderator "convert to comment" action. They're not related, so it's not a dup. :-) (But you wouldn't know that if you don't have access to the code, so I don't fault you for your educated guess.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in build 3740 for MSE/MSO, and build 2863 for other sites.

Comment: Any chance to fix the comments that were affected by the bug? :)

Comment: No, sorry. This change is not retroactive. :-(